# build fail xcode 10 error : symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 using Cocoapods ( with screen and config )

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cocoapods, podfile

i'm new to xcode and cocoapods, i try to run my app ((Using angular & ionic)**My app worked fine before adding cocoapods** ) to implement push notification with FCM and my build fail with the error message below, i've searched a lot on google and here in stackoverflow but none of the proposed solutions worked for me.
I've tried :

- added $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT) to the Architectures
- build active architecture only -> set to 'NO'
- for 'valid architectures' -> set to arm64, armv7 and armv7s
- deleted the DerivedData folder and its contents, cleaned and built
  again
- So many 'Clean Build Folder'
- Tried with and without use_frameworks! in Podfile
- deintegrating and reintegrating pods.

**Sometime the error message change to "library not found for -lPod-Myionic AppName**", i guess both errors are linked , but i dont understand why, maybe my Podfile is not set properly ?

Thanks for your help.

my conf'

```
❱ pod env
```

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.14 (18A391)
       Xcode : 10.0 (10A255)
         Git : git version 2.18.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 29f208b73b17f8bc75ee7e54da639c7302f3875b`

#### Installation Source

`Executable Path: /usr/local/bin/pod`

#### Plugins

`cocoapods-clean       : 0.0.1
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`

#### Podfile

```ruby

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'Agricommunity' do

use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Firebase'

# Pods for MyIonicApp

end

```
❱ ionic info
```

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
   ios-sim           : 7.0.0
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : macOS
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255

```
❱ cordova plugin list
```

cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase 1.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.4.6 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.3 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.8 "Diagnostic"

[screenshot of xcode error message[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq8pF.png]
[screenshot of xcode config][https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8s3x.png]

Answer (score 0):

I finally deleted cocopod stuff and use ios apns key instead of certificates in order to enable push notification in my app, so this problem is not resolved but i found a workaround.